# Snowflake - how can I update user roles dynamically with a cursor?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, cursor

I'm trying to to perform the code below.

My goal is to loop through users and update their role only if it's empty. Is this possible using a cursor this way (I want to call this from a stored procedure at the end of the day)?

Thank you!

```
DECLARE
    c1 CURSOR FOR select * from SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.USERS where default_role='';
    user_name string;
BEGIN
    OPEN c1;
    FOR user_iterator IN c1 DO
        user_name := user_iterator.LOGIN_NAME;
        alter user user_name set default_role = 'something';
        
    END FOR;
    CLOSE c1;
    RETURN 'success';
END;
```

I keep getting this error:

> User 'USER_NAME' does not exist or not authorized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably you need to wrap it with identifier:
alter user **identifier**(:user_name) set default_role = 'something';

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: I was wrong, you're right - that was the solution. I also needed to add a colon before the variable, like so: alter user identifier(:user_name). Thank you!

Comment: Great, so ahead and vote up my answer then  i just added colon on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
    c1 CURSOR FOR select * from SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.USERS where default_role='';
    user_name string;
BEGIN
    OPEN c1;
    FOR user_iterator IN c1 DO
        alter user user_iterator.LOGIN_NAME set default_role = 'something';
        
    END FOR;
    CLOSE c1;
    RETURN 'success';
END;
```